# How to make a cockpit LCD display night vision compliant?

Tags: cockpit, night-flying, display

I am trying to understand what does it means by making an LCD display compatible with Night Vision? The aircraft is an old Mirage of 1950's.

If I use an LCD display in it's cockpit display unit then how would I make the LCD compatible with Night Vision capability?

1. Do I need to select a specific color (wavelength or frequency on spectrum) to display the data on the screen?
2. Or do I need to put some filter sheet on top of the LCD screen to make its Night Vision compatible?
3. Or does it mean something other than these?

Edit:
The only info about the OEM display is follows:
"The display is an ac TFEL flat panel display combined with contrast enhancement bandpass filters to achieve both sunlight-readability and night-vision google compatibility"

I want to replace this TFEL display with an LCD display. But I dont understand how will I do night-vision google compatibility in an LCD?

Comment: What is the standard or regulation you want to be compliant to?

Comment: Can you name some of them as I don't know of these, but I can work them back wards?

Comment: @GdD I have added more details in the post related to your query.

Comment: I don't understand this, are you building a custom display or avionics system? Do you plan to use night vision goggles?

Comment: I want to replace the TFEL display with an LCD display of a cockpit display device. The TFEL display is NVG compatible.. but I don't know how will I make an LDC as NVG compatible. Do I need to use a specific RGB color on LCD display to write the data on the LCD screen OR do I need to put any extra layer/filter screen on top of the LCD display to make it NVG compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an LCD screen NVG compatible by adding a filter screen on top of the display that complies with MIL-STD-3009.  You can get a copy of MIL-STD-3009 from several commercial sources or direct from the Defense Logistics Agency [website](https://quicksearch.dla.mil/qsSearch.aspx).

There are a few companies that manufacture the filter screens. I would start with a search for NVIS filters.

Comment: The parameter is 'sunlight readability'. What makes an LCD fulfill this criterion? Is there some min 'nits' value for a cockpit display to be 'sunlight-readable'?

Comment: I don't know if there is a magic number for sunlight readability. It's a factor of brightness, contrast ratio, and the reflectivity of the front glass. You need low reflectivity to cut the glare which obscures the display. You might find some more info in the civil display standard, SAE AS8034.